# Use WebExtensions API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would bookmark page in Angular

I use the WebExtensions Api.

```
function onCreated(node) {
 console.log(node);
}

var createBookmark = browser.bookmarks.create({
  title: "bookmarks.create() on MDN",
  url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create"
});

createBookmark.then(onCreated);
```

I get this error message

```
Cannot find name 'browser'
```

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: I should adapt it to Firefox and Chrome but event when I use `chrome.bookmarks` I get `bookmarks` not defined

Comment: You need the user to grant permissions before using the api, until then it will be undefined https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks. Ask permission declaring it in the `manifest.json`

Comment: I create a manifest file in my root project tree ? I'm using Angular , how to import manifest into my application ?

Comment: I'm sorry these are unrelated questions which you can search for. All already answered on SO